# In a professional kitchen, can the use by date on raw boneless meat be ignored because it has been vacuum-packed, and if so, for how long?

Tags: food-safety

I threw it away but was told later that someone else (a professional cook/chef) had said that, as it was (supposedly) vacuum-packed, it was safe to use a few days later than the use by date.

Comment: Alternatively, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46722/do-best-by-xx-xx-xx-foods-have-an-expiration-date

Comment: The edit doesn't make it any less of a duplicate, sorry. If you want to learn basic food safety, please read our writeup under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. We tend to close as duplicagtes all questions which are already covered by the information there and in the linked questions.

Answer (score -2):

I buy most of my meat in the "last day" section ,as long as it is sealed. Sometime I cook in a week, sometime I freeze it , never a problem.