# If milk bottle says BEST BY JUNE 10/22 , how long does it last in the fridge if the bottle is opened and unopened?

Tags: food-safety, milk

Google says all opened milk lasts 4-7 days. It also says all unopened milk lasts 5-7 days.
But my bottle has a BEST BY date of JUNE 10/22 , that is 5 months. Both can't be right, Either the article is wrong or the date on my bottle is a mistake of some kind. It's Nestles brand milk. Does someone have a clue.?

As you can tell I don't usually buy milk.

Comment: Farm fresh milk goes bad much more quickly than UHT pasteurized shelf stable milk. Which type of milk did you purchase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do "Best by: XX-XX-XX" foods have an expiration date?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46722/do-best-by-xx-xx-xx-foods-have-an-expiration-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was the milk stored at ambient temperature in the place you bought it? If so, you’ve probably bought ultra heat treated (UHT) milk. This kind of milk has been through a more aggressive sterilisation process than regular milk (which is pasteurised). UHT milk lasts much longer unopened because the bacteria that make milk curdle have been killed, but has a different taste (which most people find less pleasant than fresh milk).

Comment: @ Rdd ...I never would have guessed. Thank you  That would explain it. I bought it online and used curbside but if I can find powdered Carnation skim milk that may last longer even opened. I use it to make corn bread and don't drink it.

Comment: Glad to help! UHT and powdered milk are good to cook with. UHT milk lasts longer than fresh milk even when opened, so it’s a good choice for irregular use.